# Generating cucumber.json from Behavex execution

Tags: python, automation

While executing Behavex scripts, report.json is created after the execution is completed. Can I convert behavex generated report.json to cucumber.json

I have tried to extract cucumber.json using behave2cucumber. But it didn’t work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.